# Random values of rows with minimum unique values of a column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a huge df (~1 Million rows) with a bunch of columns. One of this column contains some categorical data, like `Name`:

```
Code    Regione    CodeProv            Origin  Name
0            1     Piemonte            1       Torino
1            1     Piemonte            2       Vercelli
2            1     Piemonte            2       Vercelli
```

what I want to do is to get a random number of rows, say 10k, but these rows should contain at least 20 unique values of the `Name` columns, no matters if each unique category has the same row number.

Comment: Choose the 20 names first, and use `isin()` to choose randomly?

Comment: Have you tried using [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html)?

Comment: @Dan how does `sample` help pick 20 unique names?

Comment: @Dan I tried sample with `frac`, like `df.sample(frac=1)` to shuffle the values, but it's not what I want.

Comment: `df.sample(n=10_000)` - regarding the names, it depends on the distribution. Do you have 1000s of names, only 20 names? If your probability of picking a sample at random which satisfies your condition is reasonably high, I would just use `df.sample(n=10_000)` and if there are fewer than 20 names, pick again. Maybe you can give us more info with say `df["Name"].value_counts()`? It depends on how concentrated the distribution is.

Comment: It contains hundreds of unique values, so writing something manually is not the best choice.

Comment: You don't have to write anything manually... My question is that if you choose 10 000 rows out of 1 000 000, how high is the probability that you'll get 20 unique names? If 99% of your data are associated with say 5 names, then it's a problem. But if the distribution is more even, then `df.sample(n=10_000)` should almost always work for you. Just put it in a loop to check for the rare cases when it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

If you number of names is >> 20 and your distribution of names is not concentrated amoungst fewer than 20 names, then don't over complicate it and just do this:

```
number_of_unique_names_in_sample = 0
while number_of_unique_names_in_sample < 20:
    df_sample = df.sample(n=10_000)
    number_of_unique_names_in_sample = df_sample["Name"].nunique()
```

And maybe add in a counter to limit the number of iterations in case your distribution changes (like in a small test sample for example).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, make sense :) I thought it was a simpler (AKA standard parameter of a function, `sample` in this case for example).

Comment: I'm surprised its not. You might be able to hack something out of sklearn's train_test_split which has a `stratify` parameter though. Or just look internally how they implemented it for inspiration.

Comment: btw I would recommend this approach only if it mostly works first time. If it takes like 10 loops to find 20 unique names then it might not be the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what your asking for

```
name_cols = [list_of_names]
samples_per_name = 500
```

`df[df['Name'].isin(name_cols)].groupby('Name').apply(lambda x: x.sample(samples_per_name))`

the result will be 10000 rows with `len(name_cols)` (20 in your example) each containing 500 rows

Comment: I'm getting: `NameError: name 'sample' is not defined`

Comment: oops I meant `x.sample`, calling the `sample` function on each `groupby` object